# Python socket scan multiple IP's from CSV Issue

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to create a script that will scan all my servers and let me know if it can scan that server or not.

Currently I am using the libraries csv and socket to accomplish this.

The issue I am running into is when this runs, it runs fine for the first 5 IP's in my list, but once it successfully scans one of my servers and reports it as up it instantly fills in the rest of the logs with my "Host" is unreachable print statement.

And gives me WinError 10056 for unreachable IP's and reports the error WinError 10061 for all the entries after it successfully scans and reports the first available IP as ip. I know that the other IP's are up and running and should be reporting as up, I can scan them individually using this same script without issue.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Example of what my csv would like:

```
Servers         Port
192.168.1.200   12334
192.168.1.201   43222
192.168.1.202   24
192.168.1.203   5
192.168.1.204   8080
192.168.1.205   445
192.168.1.206   5
192.168.1.207   5
192.168.1.218   443
192.168.1.219   80
192.168.1.220   8834
192.168.1.221   80
```

```
import csv
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


def portScanner():
    with open('IPAddress.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:

            Host = str(row['Servers'])
            Port = int(row['Port'])
            Scan = sock.connect_ex((Host, Port))
            sock.settimeout(int(30))

            if Scan:
                print(f"Scanning Complete: {Host} is Offline or Port {Port} is unreachable.")
                print("DEBUG: " + str(Scan))
            else:
                print(f"Scanning Complete: {Host} is reachable on Port {Port}.")
                print("DEBUG: " + str(Scan))


portScanner()
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use nmap instead

Comment: Maybe it is about trying to open a new connection with the same socket after you have already used it to connect other hosts? In that case closing it with mysocket.close() should help.

Comment: Along with other suggestions in comments, try adding a delay between each requests, as it is possible that your router/proxy could have blocked further connections due to frequent connection requests, to prevent DDoS attack.